# Get black screen in middle of boot squence using plymouth

Tags: raspbian, plymouth

I'm using Plymouth to have a splash screen on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian (Stretch) and up to the middle of sequence, the screen background becomes black and just updates are shown. The boot sequence doesn't fail, just becomes in part black.

For example in 'script' Plymouth theme, at start blue background with the Debian logo in the middle of screen, and at the middle of boot only Debian logo with blue background the rest of screen becoming black.

I've tested with other themes fade-in, glow, joy, solar, spacefun, etc. All have the same trouble.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this same problem. I haven't found a good fix.

The workaround I've got so far is to reload the image sprite during refresh or progress callbacks, like so:

```
fun refresh_callback ()
  {
    # (Normally)Currently we do nothing here
    bg_sprite = Sprite(resized_bg_image);
    bg_sprite.SetZ(-10000);

  }

Plymouth.SetRefreshFunction (refresh_callback);
```

In my script, `resized_bg_image` is a scaled version of my background image.

Maybe there is some kind of mode switch or blanking that the kernel is doing to the framebuffer since Jessie and the Plymouth script plugin seems to be unaware of it.

As above, this isn't a great solution, there is still some 'flicker' when the background goes blank.

However, it does get the background back and keep things looking reasonably good.

Comment: I don't find a good fix too, just put background black and use update status to draw a logo `SetUpdateStatusFunction(text)
{
  draw_logo();
}
Plymouth.SetUpdateStatusFunction(SetUpdateStatusFunction);` +1 happy to see I'm not alone nor crazy.